# `django-constance` in the distribution, it do not generate the data.

Tags: python, django

`django-constance` in the distribution, it do not generate the data.

This is my distribution MySQL.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

there is no data in it.

---

this is the configurations of my constance in `settings.py`

```
CONSTANCE_BACKEND = 'constance.backends.database.DatabaseBackend'

CONSTANCE_IGNORE_ADMIN_VERSION_CHECK = True

CONSTANCE_ADDITIONAL_FIELDS = {
    'coupon_select': ['django.forms.fields.ChoiceField', {
        'widget': 'django.forms.Select',
        'choices': ((0, "时+分+秒"), (1, "时+分"), (2, "时"), (3, "忽略"))
    }],
}

CONSTANCE_CONFIG = {
    '站点名称': ('南京诗远启', '网站标题'),  # key: (default, help_text) 建议全部使用str格式作为value.统一点
    '站点描述': ('南京诗远启', '站点描述'),

    '电子券固定代码': ('DreamGo', '电子券固定代码'),
    '电子券时间': (0, '电子券时间格式', 'coupon_select'),
    '分配短信清零时间': (1, '分配短信清零时间'),

    'PayPal支付密钥': ('abcdefghijklmn', 'PayPal支付密钥'),

}

CONSTANCE_CONFIG_FIELDSETS = {
    '站点设置': ('站点名称', '站点描述'),
}
```

I also use

```
python3 manage.py migrate database
```

to migrate the table.

But why the `constance_config` table do not have the configuration data?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this blog,but there is some mistake, in `INSTALLED_APPS` it's should be

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'constance',
    'constance.backends.database',
]
```

not

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'constance',
]
```

I will correct this later.

The [blog](https://blog.dreamgotech.com/article/33/) is updated,you can follow this and try it again.

Comment: you are the first one who get the table created but not date inside this table,you can try to recreate the database. can you post you constance version,i will test it myself?

Comment: `Version: 2.2.0`.

Comment: I just create a demo with v2.2 and everything work fine,you can see my updated  [blog](https://www.yinkh.top/article/33/) and drop the old database then try again.